# Excel: IF clause for full column matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure this question has been already asked a few times, but i'm about to get crazy and looking for some help...
I have an Excel Like:

[Example of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ydP.png)

My question is, IF B1 is equal to one of A column, D1 should be C value which matched A th number.

Comment: This is either `INDEX()` + `MATCH()` or a solution using a more recent function like `FILTER()` or `XLOOKUP()`. There are a lot of similar questions around on SO. I'll see if I can forward you to any. **EDIT:** I found an old one that will also include some information on why the linked answer would work for you. Note you'd need to wrap it in an `IFERROR()`. I also linked a 2nd one with an example for `XLOOKUP()` too, no need for `IFERROR()` there.

Comment: One of main problem is to bring C value that matched number. I have added problem example. I couldn't create formula...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5;B1)>0;INDEX($C$1:$C$5;MATCH(B1;$A$1:$A$5;0));"Not found")
```

Comment: Amazing.. Many Thanks.